# Multiple views with nested states angular UI router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to have multiple views that each contain nested states in **Angular UI-Router**?

For example, in the following could `view1@main` contain nested states?  Lets say `Main` contains two page sections and `view1@main` contains a list that dynamically populates data in a view which I want to nest.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div ui-view="view1">

      <!--this is inside the template for view1-->
      <div class="myList">
          <!--ng-repeat each with a click setting the nested view-->
      </div>

      <div ui-view>
      <!--this would be another template that -->
      <!--changes based on the click from the ng-repeat -->
      </div>
  </div>

  <div ui-view="view2"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
.state('main', {
     url: '/main',
     controller: 'MainCtrl',
     views: {
          '': {
              templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
          },
          'view1@main': {
               templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
               controller: 'MainCtrl'
               //nested states in here
          },
          'view2@main': {
                templateUrl: 'views/view2.html',
                controller: 'SecondCtrl'
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why multiples views is not enough for your application?

Comment: Because in one of my views I have a list which controls content that is also on the page at the same time.  So I wanted to be able to add an `a` tag to the list items in `view1` with a `ui-serif='view1.content1'` and so on

Comment: did you managed tot solve this? - same problem here